# wpf combobox function operating on a delay

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

```
    private void messageTypeMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string option = messageTypeMenu.Text;
        if (option.Equals("Errors"))
        {
            LogParser.information = false;
            LogParser.messages = false;
            LogParser.errors = true;
        }
        if (option.Equals("Information"))
        {
            LogParser.information = true;
            LogParser.messages = false;
            LogParser.errors = false;
        }
        if (option.Equals("Messages"))
        {
            LogParser.information = false;
            LogParser.messages = true;
            LogParser.errors = false;
        }
    }
```

is a function that is supposed to update a static class depending on the selected value. however, its operating on a delay and im not sure why.

for some context, information, messages, and errors are 3 different message type for logs stored in a file that i am parsing. when someone selected information and hits view or save, they should only get the logs of that type. however, it appears to be operating on a delay.

for example, if i load in a file of logs and select information, it will show me the whoel file. then if i switch to messages, i will see only the information. then if i switch back to information, it will only show messages and so on. it seems like the combobox is looking at the value that was already present when they go to change this, but im not sure why.

Comment: This method needs something like a call to UpdateView or whatever it is that sync's up the menu selection to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to stay synchronized with the window, you should consider using the observable pattern and implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` combined with bindings. You will need to redesign your application since you can't implement interfaces on static classes but that may be worth it.

Another way would be using [Dependency Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx).